# C# winform send request content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded with Restsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, restsharp

I am developing an small app with C# window form.
I can use Restsharp to send any request with content type **application/json**. But with **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** the server always return nothing or **Internal error**.

I have tested this api with Postman and Restlet Client and it work well.
Following some example on internet but it not work too.

Here is my code:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.nhimanhma.com");
var request = new RestRequest("users/sign_in", Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
string formData = $"token={token}&user[email]={email}&user[password]={password}";
string urlEncode = RestSharp.Extensions.StringExtensions.UrlEncode(formData);

request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", urlEncode, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Can you post the code you wrote to do this?

Comment: Without looking at your code it's not possible to tell what's wrong with it

Comment: Postman can generate Restsharp code so do that with a working request and see what it looks like.

Comment: I have generate Restsharp with Postman, but look like it use multipart/form-data. And the response code is Not Acceptable.